# Fluent API Table Scaffolding - HasBaseType

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, fluent, ef-fluent-api

I have two entities in my project `Student` and `Teacher` which share a common base class, `AccountModel`. The base class contains properties that are required by both students and teachers *(semantically, both students and teachers are account holders, and for good practice, this prevents violation of the DRY principle)*

In my Fluent API config I have:

```
builder
    .Ignore<AccountModel>();

builder
    .Entity<Student>()
    .HasBaseType<AccountModel>()
    .ToTable("Students");

builder
    .Entity<Teacher>()
    .HasBaseType<AccountModel>()
    .ToTable("Teachers");
```

But when EF scaffolds a migration and generates a new database, I get an `AccountModel` table, but not a `Students` or `Teachers` table. What gives?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance), currently EF Core supports only TPH pattern, hence the database table you get. I have no idea what's the purpose of `HasBaseType`.

Comment: @IvanStoev what is the TPH pattern?

Comment: Single table containing all descendant fields plus "discriminator" column :)

Comment: Similar to https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, Entity Framework Core only supports the Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) pattern for mapping inheritance (http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance), which is why the migration results in one table for all types.

[Table per concrete type](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3170) (TPC) is on the backlog and is actively being considered, as is the [Table Per Type](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2266) (TPT) pattern.